# Dual space of continuous functions on an open set of $\mathbb{R}^m$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $V \subset \mathbb{R}^m$ be an open subset and define
$$
C(V) := \{f:V \rightarrow \mathbb{C}| f\text{ is continuous}\}.
$$
We can make $C(V)$ into a topological vector space as follow. Let $Q_1 \subseteq Q_2 \subseteq \cdots \subset V$ be compact sets such that $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty} Q_n = V$ and consider the semi-norm $\|\cdot\|_n$ defined by $$\|f\|_n := \|f\|_{L^{\infty}(C(Q_n))}.$$ These semi-norms separate elements in $C(V)$ and the topology induced by these semi-norms makes $C(V)$ into a topological vector space.

My question: What is the topological dual of C(V)?

*Remark:* It is easy to see that to every continuous linear functional on $C(Q_n)$, there corresponds a continuous linear functional on $C(V)$ because if $\phi \in C(Q_n)^{*}$ and $f\in C(V)$, then $\tilde{\phi}(f) := \phi(f|_{Q_n})$ is an element of $C(V)^*$. We know the dual space $C(Q_n)^*$ from Riesz representation theorem and $C(Q_n)^*$ consists of complex Borel measures on $Q_n$. Is there any other linear functional $\psi \in C(V)^*$ such that $\psi \notin C(Q_n)^*$ for any $n$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every continuous linear functional $\phi$ on $C(V)$ is continuous with respect to one of the given seminorms $\|\cdot\|_{Q_n}$ (supremum over $Q_n$). Using Tietze's extension theorem you then define a continuous linear functional $\tilde\phi$ on $C(Q_n)$ by $\tilde\phi(g)=\phi(f)$ where $f\in C(V)$ is any extension (this is well defined because $|\phi(f)|\le c\|f\|_{Q_n}$)). Then represent $\tilde\phi$ by a signed measure. The conclusion is that the dual of $C(V)$ is given by all signed measures with compact support.

Comment: Thanks! Can you please elaborate on the first sentence "Every continuous linear functional..."?

Comment: This is most basic locally convex theory:  Continuity of $\phi$ at $0$ gives a $0$-neighbourhood $U$ on which $|\phi|\le 1$ holds, and $U$ contains a ball of the form $\{f\in C(V): \|f\|_{Q_n}\le \varepsilon\}$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!